# hook_file_download not triggered

Tags: hooks, files

I set the private file system to `/system/files/export` , I create a file in private directory programmatically and it not belong to any field ,and show link to user , I implement `Hook_file_download` , I want check some condition in it but when user click on link to download the file created in private path it return me **Forbidden** and `mymodule_file_download` not tirggered ( I put some code to it , even die but never called).
I clear cache but noting changes,
the link that showed for user is `http://localhost/mytestdrupal/system/files/export/Export-couponcards-1393307265.csv`
where is problem?

Part of my code to create file in submit

```
function mymodule_export_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
    $temp1 = variable_get('file_private_path');
    if (!file_prepare_directory($temp1, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Problem in write file in directory'), 'error');
        return;
    }
    $filename = 'Export-file'. '.csv';
    $filepath = $temp1 . '/' . $filename;
    $df = fopen($filepath, 'w');
    if (!$df) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Can not write file in') . $filepath, 'error');
        return;
    }
            fputcsv($df, array('code', 'name'));
            fputcsv($df, array('test','test'));

    fclose($df);
    $path = file_create_url($filepath);
    drupal_set_message(t('Export done. ') . '<a href="' . $path . '">' . t('Download export file') . '</a>');
}
```

Comment: Can you post link shown to user ? It should be system/files/***

Comment: link is `http://localhost/mytestdrupal/system/files/export/Export-couponcards-1393307265.csv`

Comment: Can you post the hook implementation ? That will give us better idea what you are doing and why you are getting forbidden message ..

Comment: 1. Are folder and files permissions correct? 2. check virtual host's (.htaccess) configuration. 3. Check server log, may be you can find something interesting.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious but it looks like the above code is saving a file to the public directory `variable_get('file_public_path');` not the private file path. Note also the menu callback uses `system/files` but your private folder path should probably be different, e.g `sites/default/files/private` or somewhere outside the webroot.

Comment: @xurshid29 I am working on local , in wamp,

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry after It not worked for me , I change it to public in our module, after `Anil Sagar` ask me to come code in question I copy it from new version and forgot revert it to `private`.

Answer (score 1):

hook_file_download working perfectly, List of steps which worked for me

1. I made File System to Private
2. Created a File Field in Article Content Type and marked it as Private In Settings
3. Uploaded a PDF File
4. Link to file is something link below

http://example.com/d7/system/files/****.pdf

Created a custom module with hook_file_download, When ever i access above URL and visit any page i can see drupal set message "Hi"

```
function drup_custom_file_download($uri) {
  drupal_set_message("Hi");
}
```

Comment: I said I created file programmatically ,and not belong to any field

Comment: How did you created programatically ? Can you post the code. It should be through file API so that any entry exist in file Table.

Comment: I update question with part of my code that create file

Comment: Can you save your file using https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_data/7 and try the same ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be in a file field or the drupal managed files table. If you want access to be controlled by file_file_download() then you do but if you have your own hook_file_download() implementation you don't.

Comment: @rooby but I implement hook_file_download , but it not work.

Comment: @AnilSagar ,yes I can,but what is relation between file table and hook_file_download, as its documentation its work according uri

Answer (score 1):

First you need to verify your file is being saved to the correct place.

You say you want to save to a sub-directory 'export' but that is not what your code is doing.

You should be saving to the private file system, not the public one. So `variable_get('file_private_path', '')` instead of `variable_get('file_public_path')`.

Then append you export directory, so it would be:

```
$temp1 = variable_get('file_private_path', '') . '/export';
```

Then if you file is successfully saved at `/sites/default/files/private/export` (or wherever your private files should be), then you are ready for the next step.

When making the link to the file you have to pass in a uri, so

```
$path = file_create_url($filepath);
```

should be something like:

```
$path = file_create_url('private://export/' . $filename);
```

Using the 'private' stream wrapper means that internal links match to /sites/default/files/private (or whatever you have `variable_get('file_private_path', '')` set to) and external links generate like www.example.com/system/files/...

For more information see: [DrupalPrivateStreamWrapper](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!stream_wrappers.inc/class/DrupalPrivateStreamWrapper/7)

Comment: sorry, after private not worked , I changed it to public and paste here without notice that it is change to public, it public , I set the private file system to 'system/files/export' ;

Comment: Private file system should be something like sites/default/files/private, unless you actually have a directory on the file system that is system/files. system/files is a drupal url, not an actual directory on the file system.

Comment: First I set it to something if 'defaults/files/private/` after I chnage it to `/system/files/export` there are exist directory and file create correctly (I check it)